# What is the role of the Vice-President in Turkey?

Tags: constitution, turkey, vice-president, turkish-referendum-2017

The constitutional amendments approved by the April 2017 referendum allow President   Erdoğan to appoint one or more Vice-Presidents.

Who is eligible for the role, and what will their duties be?

Comment: If he appoints more than one, realistically the role will be infighting to see which one of them is the most important one.

Answer (score 2):

Their main function is to stand-in for the absence of the president and be a leader on the National Security Council.

According to a [translation of the Turkish constitution](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-REF(2017)005-e), they serve as a temporary president until an election chooses the next president when there is no longer a president.

> ARTICLE 106 – After being elected, the President may appoint one or more Vice-Presidents.  In case the office of the President falls vacant for any reason, the election of the President shall be held in forty five days.  Until a new one is elected, the **Vice-President shall act as president**, and he/she shall exercise the powers of the President.[1](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-REF(2017)005-e)- page 16 of the translation

They serve as [acting-president](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-REF(2017)005-e) if the president is sick or out of the country or for whatever reason is unable to carry his/her duties.

> In the event of a temporary absence of the President of the Republic on account of illness, travel abroad or similar circumstances, **the Vice-President shall serve as Acting
>   President of the Republic** and exercise the powers of the President of the Republic. [1](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-REF(2017)005-e) - page 16.

They are considered members of the [National Security Council.](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-REF(2017)005-e)

> 2. National Security Council
>      ARTICLE 118- (As amended on October 3, 2001; Act No. 4709) The National Security Council shall be composed of **Vice-Presidents**, ministers of Justice, National Defence, Internal Affairs, and Foreign Affairs, the Chief of the General Staff, the commanders of the Land, Naval and Air Forces, under the chairpersonship of the President of the Republic. [1](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-REF(2017)005-e) page 21.

They are also influential in setting the Turkish NSC agenda and are [chairmen](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-REF(2017)005-e) of that body when the president is absent.

> The agenda of the National Security Council shall be drawn up by the President of the Republic taking into account the proposals of **Vice-Presidents** and the Chief of the General Staff.
>
> In the absence of the President of the Republic, the National Security Council shall convene under the chairpersonship of the **Vice-President**. [1](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-REF(2017)005-e) page 22